# How to make successive api calls in redux saga from an array not knowing it's size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

What I want to do is to upload multiple files consecutively from an array and save their response in an array :

```
function* uploadTransactionFilesWorker({ payload: { onFail, onSuccess, data } }) {
  try {
       const { transactions } = data;

       const finalData = yield transactions.map(item => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", item.document[0], item.document[0].name);
            call(uploadFile(formDataA));
        });

          onSuccess(finalData);
      } catch (e) {
          onFail(e);
      }
 }
```

but this doesn't seem to work. can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I did't test `.map` with `yield` before, but by looking at your use case I think we can easily use an `while` loop with `yield` to have async code working in sync syntax

basic idea

```js
let array = [ .... ]

let i = 0;

while( i < array.length ){
  try{

    yield call(upoadFile(...));
    yield put(onSuccess());

  } catch(e){

    yield put(onFail());
  }

  i++;
}
```